# Ember update an object in an array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an `ArrayController` with a `data:[]` property and a template with an each loop.

When I do

```
this.data.push({object})
```

the data array is updated, but the view is not.

When I do

```
this.data.pushObject({object})
```

the data array is updated AND the view is updated too (hooray).

When I do

```
this.data[0] = {new object}
```

the data array is updated, but the view is not.

What is the equivalent of pushObject for this case?

I cannot find a "updateObject" method. There is the setObjects method, but it weirdly fails. Some objects are updated and some are not.

The objects are like:

```
{
    item: "item",
    array: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

The item is always updated, and the array not always. I have nested each loops in the template; could it be a problem?

The template is like:

```
{{#each data}}

    {{item}}

    {{foo}}

    {{#each array}}
        {{this}}
    {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

The way I edit is like (in the controller):

```
var itemToEdit = self.get('data')[0];
itemToEdit['array'] = [2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Globally speaking, the problem is that the view does not re-render. When I go to another route and then back to the current route, everything is properly rendered with all the updates I made.

** PROGRESS:
When I do

```
self.get('data').setEach('foo', Math.random());
```

the foo property is properly set and updated in the view... Where on Earth is the "set" method for a property of an array element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your objects is a plain JavaScript object. You need to change to `Ember.Objects`. Instead of

```
this.data.pushObject({ foo: 'bar' })
```

you need to use

```
this.data.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({ foo: 'bar' })).
```

The `Ember.Object` is neeeded, so you can use the set method, to update the views.

Comment: This is not what I want to do. insertAt will insert an object in my array ; I already have all the items I need in my array, now I want to update them. The replace method looked interesting, but it does not work for a reason I don't understand yet

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought that you wanted a `this.data[0]` version that observe changes. Can you update your question to show how you send the data to the template, the template itself, and how you are changing the data?

Comment: Thanks. Based on your update I think that `itemToEdit.set('array', [2, 3, 4, 5]);` will work

Comment: It throws an error : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'. Which is really weird because when I log the object, I can see the " get array: function () { "

Comment: Each of your objects is a plain js object, you need to change to `Ember.Object`s. Instead of `this.data.pushObject({ foo: 'bar' })` you need to use `this.data.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({ foo: 'bar' }))`. The Ember.Object is neeeded so you can use the `set` method, to update the views.

Comment: YES ! that was the problem ! You saved my day :) (I did edit your answer)

Comment: A day worth of searching the web for this until I came along this... Something so simple...